# Archive project using combine

Tags: swift, xcode, combine

I'm trying to build an iOS app, that has minimum target set to iOS 10. 
In my app, I have a piece a code that uses new Combine framework (for iOS 13+).

When I archive the app, Xcode tell me `error: no such module 'Combine'`

Is it not possible to use Combine if our target is set to less that iOS 13?

Comment: no you can't use it on iOS 13, see the supported SDK's: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, any targets utilising the new Combine framework will have to be set to a min iOS 13.